# Product's reviews not displaying in single page in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, review

I am trying to get reviews in single product page. To do that I am using - 
`<?php $_items = $block->getReviewsCollection()->getItems(); ?>`

But after putting this, I am getting:

> **Fatal error :** Call to a member function getItems() on
>   null...... .

why i am getting this error? any suggestion would be appreciate.

Comment: In which file you are using this code ?

Comment: I create a custom file (single page file) "view.php" inside Magento_Catalog\product\. and i am calling the list.phtml file which is inside Magento_Review\product\view\list. and the above code is using inside list.phtml file.

Comment: Then it have to work. Check your file path like 'Magento_Review/templates/product/view/list.phtml'. also check the class of $block.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But not getting your mean. please elaborate your answer. :-)